# Bad Request when POSTing GeoJSON Data using php

Tags: php, geojson

I have this php code that POSTs GeoJSON data to a service called AirMap to retrieve relevant rulesets for flying UAS.

index.php

```
<?
$ch = curl_init();

$json_data = '"geometry":' + '{ "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
      ]
   }';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.airmap.com/rules/v1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$'{");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data); 

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Api-Key: (removed)";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

echo "$result";
?>
```

Whenever I execute this code, the page displays

"Bad Request"

index.php 2

```
<?
$ch = curl_init();

$json_data = '{ "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
      ]
   }';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.airmap.com/rules/v1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$'{");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data); 

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "X-Api-Key: (removed)";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

echo "$result";
?>
```

Whenever I execute that code, it displays

```
{"status":"fail","data":{"message":"parameter validation failed","data":[{"name":"geometry","message":"Invalid param"},{"name":"geometry","message":"A valid geometry must be included."},{"name":"type","message":"Parameter not allowed."},{"name":"coordinates","message":"Parameter not allowed."}]}}
```

I tried to understand what that means, but I just am currently at a dead end. The documentation (and error code) says that the "geometry" part is required, so that's why I added it. The documentation is at https://developers.airmap.com/docs/rulesets, and I've already run the GeoJSON through a GeoJSON linter, and it passed.

Comment: have you tried contacting their customer support?

Comment: another suggestion is don't write json string by hand, just create a structured array similar to their requirement and use `json_encode` instead

Comment: Thanks, I was planning to do that. This was just the beginning step before I was going to do that but I will definitely try that.

Comment: Also, I have attempted `$json_data2 = '"geometry": { \"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [ [ [ -118.37099075317383, 33.85505651142062 ], [ -118.37305068969727, 33.85502978214579 ], [ -118.37347984313963, 33.854673391015496 ], [ -118.37306141853333, 33.85231226221667 ], [ -118.37193489074707, 33.85174201755203 ], [ -118.36997151374815, 33.85176874785573 ], [ -118.36995005607605, 33.8528112231754 ], [ -118.37099075317383, 33.85505651142062 ] ] ] }';` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted AirMap support and they helped me out. Since they require an additional flag (geometry) to be passed with the cURL request, those also require an opening and closing curly brace. So the geometry portion would look something like this:

```
$json_data2 = '{"geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -118.37099075317383, 33.85505651142062 ], [ -118.37305068969727, 33.85502978214579 ], [ -118.37347984313963, 33.854673391015496 ], [ -118.37306141853333, 33.85231226221667 ], [ -118.37193489074707, 33.85174201755203 ], [ -118.36997151374815, 33.85176874785573 ], [ -118.36995005607605, 33.8528112231754 ], [ -118.37099075317383, 33.85505651142062 ] ] ] }}';
```

Comment: yes, always contact support, just like what i've said in the comments, they will know everything there is in their API compared to people here on SO

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

what I find confusing is this part:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$'{");`

[...]

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);`

Are you certain that this both are combined? Maybe the first part is just overwritten?

**Update**

After looking at your code I found the following difference to the example on their ruleset example:

```
$json_data = '"geometry":' + '{ "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
      ]
}';
```

This is wrong because `+` is not for concatenating strings `.` is. I tried correcting the other parts with apostrophs too, resulting in this:

```
$json_data = '{"geometry": "{ \\"type\\": \\"Polygon\\",
    \\"coordinates\\": [
      [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
      ]}"
}';
```

Comment: Nice catch. What's funny is that the first part is actually unnecessary (so it's fine that it is overwritten) and it still returned Bad Request when I removed the line. I'm starting to think it's something on AirMap's end.

Comment: @rhw55 I see you have come to the same concusion as I am. If we helped, consider upvoting our answers and select your answer as the correct one. This will help others.